# Идея для Java-проекта

Tags: java

У меня есть команда из 4 участников и один ментор. Нам нужен проект, который будет затрагивать темы (желательно все):

1. Серверная часть
2. Основы ОПП
3. Сложные виды данных
4. Возможность интегрирования на базу Android
5. Система контроля версии. Git
6. (Графическая часть)
7. Новые библиотеки

Мы готовы изучать новые возможности языка и совершенствовать свои умения. Очень хотелось бы, чтобы потом никто не постеснялся показать данный проект своему будущему работодателю. Также интересует, чтобы темы была прикладной, то есть, программа решала какую-то проблему, хоть и незначительную. Спасибо!

Comment: Программа генерирующая идеи для проектов.

Comment: Ребят, вы гении

Comment: Забавно, но на всех стартап тусовках учат, что идеи ничего не стоят. Да, с этим можно согласиться..., но отчасти, т.к. если бы это было так, то не возникало бы подобных этому сообщений.

Comment: Да даже бота для телеграмма..

Comment: А что надо для написания бота?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы в полной мере задействовать всё то, что вы перечислили, вам необходимо в своем проекте реализовать следующее:

1. веб сервис с доступом по API и сайт к нему
2. мобильное приложение.

Сейчас бум разных мессенджеров. Создайте свой, но необычный, скажем, для скрытого общения. Для формирования и отправки сообщения используется качелька громкости смартфона, а для приёма служит вибросигнал. Получится что-то типа мессенджера-морзянки.

Comment: Спасибо за идею! Обсудим в группе, и еще раз спасибо!

Comment: Да, не за что. Обращайтесь, могу еще подкинуть идей.

Answer (score 2):

Еще одна хорошая идея - Telegram Bot.
Tg Bot для любых целей - поиск картинок, поиск информации, контроль чего либо(умного дома например), и т.п.

Тут вам и серверная часть, и Telegram API, и новые либы, и сложные типы данных, и т.п.

Git - будет у вас в любом проекте, с которым вы работаете сообща(в т.ч. и в Tg Bot). 
Советую еще изучить Maven и JUnit тестирование.

Правда, тут вам не придется писать под Андроид и граф. часть, т.к. все это уже написано. Вы можете интегрировать свой проект с проектом выше - сделать так, что бы люди могли общаться в вашем мессенджере с помощью Telegramm - переписываясь с ботом, а из бота сообщения идут в ваш мессенджер. А ответы бота - сообщения других участников.